# AWS WebServer architecture (ELB + iptables)

Tags: nginx, iptables, amazon-web-services, varnish, amazon-elb

I'm currently working on the architecture of high-traffic high-availability website.

We are using AWS.

Currently, we have:

Route 53 -> ELB -> Multiple EC2 instances -> RDS Multi AZ.

Each EC2 instance runs Varnish + Nginx & PHP FCGI. Sessions and some other shared data are stored via ElastiCache.

We plan to run Varnish and Nginx on each EC2 instance because this allow us to reduce failure points and to simply run extra instances if the load increases.

However, we have to add iptables (fail2ban) to this. Of course, we get the IP of the ELB instead of the real client ip...

We thought about the following solutions:

1) Add an EC2 instance between Route 53 and ELB, running iptables/firewalls (and maybe varnish ?) and forwarding everything to ELB.

2) Replace ELB by a custom EC2 running HAProxy + iptables.

3) Use mod_security and build some custom stuff to dynamically blacklist IPs

4) Stick with the current architecture and remove iptables from our todo-list.

What would be a good approach ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

## x-forwarded-for header

> Of course, we get the IP of the ELB instead of the real client ip...

You'll want to make use of the x-forwarded-for header which will give you the client ip.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#x-forwarded-for

> The X-Forwarded-For request header helps you identify the IP address
>   of a client when you use HTTP/HTTPS load balancer.

---

Here's some other stuff you may be interested in ...

## Security Groups & Network ACLs

AWS provide two great security features that operate in the same area iptables does:

- Security Groups
- Network ACLs

Security groups (think replacement for iptables) give you the ability to allow/deny traffic based on ip and port. There are other features around supplying another AWS resource in place of an ip address.

Network ACLs give you further control of your network. You can allow/deny traffic based on ip and port within and between subnets within your VPC.

## AWS Security

- If you're using VPC you have the ability to put things like EC2s in private subnets.
- ELBs that need to be public facing can have just the essentials exposed (443, 80).
- You can lock down services like SSH to a whitelist of IPs.
- If you have an application with a web-interface for administration, you can lock it down at the web-server level to protect against any vulnerabilities at the software level.

## Adding your own security to EC2s

If you're looking to add additional security measures on your EC2s (like fail2ban) and you're using multiple EC2s behind a load balancer, you'll need to engineer your EC2s so that they don't have any unique data on them (there's no point in adding a rule o EC2 #1 if it's not on EC2 #2).

There are techniques to keep EC2s in sync with each other, things like storing data on S3, pulling configuration management from a master, or pulling content from the same repo. Using Golden images along with bootstrap scripts (that pull data from S3).

## Answers to your questions

> 1) Add an EC2 instance between Route 53 and ELB, running
>   iptables/firewalls (and maybe varnish ?) and forwarding everything to
>   ELB.

Adding an EC2 instance in front of your ELB is going to diminish your ability to scale. You also create a single point of failure so you likely do not want to do this.

> 2) Replace ELB by a custom EC2 running HAProxy + iptables.

You could do this but it comes at the cost of managing it yourself. You become responsibile for the software, security, updates, availability etc. You want to avoid this if possible (ie only do this if you can't solve the problem using an ELB).

> 3) Use mod_security and build some custom stuff to dynamically blacklist IPs

This is an option, but you may want to manage security at the OS/Network level, not (just) at the software/app level.

> 4) Stick with the current architecture and remove iptables from our todo-list.

Sure that's an option, but is that acceptable for the business/project?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm already using the x-forwarded-for header to get the real client ip in nginx and varnish, however this doesn't solve the problem of iptables which is at application level, thus doesn't understand HTTP header. I'm also using security groups, but it's not dynamic like fail2ban with iptables are.

Comment: I imagine you'd be able to script this if you really wanted to.